# How to create a correct entity-relationship diagram (ERD) about a video game profits scenario

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I'm starting to build my application database, and I'm really new to the this world, so I have a lot of doubts about my ERD and if its entity types and relationships are ok.

This is an application that calculates how much me and my friends profit in a video game and saves all the data so we can check it later. I'll explain it a bit so you can understand the ERD.

We want to save this data about every Hunt:

- Where the HUNT was (RESPAWN)
- How many people we were (1 to 4)
- The date of the HUNT
- How much everyone WASTE (Knight, Druid, Paladin, Sorcerer and the
  Total)
- The loot value
- The HUNT balance
- How many profit we did (each one of us)
- The amount of money everyone have to recieve (paying waste + profit
  -> TRANSFER)
- And if the HUNT is already paid or not

I'm already doing all the math and saving this data in a *.txt* file for the moment, but I want to take the next step and build a decent database, and to make sure the following diagram is ok:

[image: My ERD]

Are some relationships wrong? Do you think I should add more entity types, properties, etc.?

Answer (score -1):

A question I have is what is the significance of the _EK/_ED columns? I can assume they are separate columns for each person in your party? If that is so, this design would have a lot of NULL values for whenever there isn't 4 people in a hunt, and will outright prevent accounting for a 5 person hunt. I hesitate to suggest a more flexible design until I can better understand what exactly each column is for. I would be happy to expand on what you have if you could post some sample data, such as from a hunt or two, along with a quick explanation of where the information is coming from.

I would also review the datatypes chosen. SMALLINT is fine for key id fields, but it would be best to choose a DATE or DATETIME for your hunt date, instead of varchar. The Paid column has two issues that I see. Including a question mark is not encouraged, instead keep it to alpha-numeric and maybe underscores. If the only two options for that field are Yes/No, then it can be a bit datatype. That way you only store 0 for no, and 1 for yes. That saves a lot of space compared to varchars, and prevents you from having "Yes","YES", and "yes", which are all seen as different depending on your chosen software.